# S3 bundled download

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, zip

I have a page on my site that allows the user to select what files they want to download. Upon submit it bundles these files on the fly into one zipfile that they can download.

This works great, but these files are all stored local to the server.  I now have moved all my files to S3.

I am trying to think of a way to give the user all the files with one click and serve them from S3.

The site is built in asp.net/C#.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this problem before, what I ended up doing was building the zip and uploading the zip into another s3 bucket when the generation was complete and serving it from there.  Then just "periodically" removing the zips from s3.

Comment: What would be the difference of having the user downloading the zip from the server vs basically S3 downloading the zip from the server? I don't understand how there would be a performance benefit by doing what you describe?

Comment: well the biggest thing for me was 1) no files from my web server, this was important from a load balancing perspective 2) S3 seemed to perform faster too 3) no need to provision huge amounts of storage on the web server to support all the zip files (they were media files).  At the end of the day you cant serve a file from S3 thats not there. (the first S is simple)